# Acessar MySQL com C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Estou criando um `Form` simples que tem 3 `TextBoxes` e 3 botões e quero guardar a informação digitada nos `Textboxes` numa tabela.

Já criei as `querys` todas dentro de uma classe `acessoBD`, mas não consigo acessar o **MySQL**.
O **MySQL** está integrado com o Visual Studio, lá em *server explorer* eu consigo mexer na *database*, criar tabelas, etc. O problema é na hora de rodar o programa e pedir acesso a ele via `SqlConnection`. Quando tentei com `SqlConnection` dava **error 40**, agora com `SqlCeConnection` (vi em um tópico que essa mudança poderia solucionar o problema) está apontando um novo erro.

Segue a imagem[image: errosql]

Comment: Daniel, na sua imagem, em nenhum momento você está acessando o banco. E mais importante ainda, você está tentando acessar um banco MySQL usando o providader do SQLServer, desse jeito não vai mesmo rs. Você deve instalar o pacote do mysql.
Veja alguns links que podem te ajudar: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp http://www.macoratti.net/08/08/c_mysql1.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primeira coisa: você está tentando se conectar ao **MySQL** usando [`SqlCeConnection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/1cty35hs%28v=vs.100%29) que é uma classe para se conectar ao **SQL Server**.

Para se conectar a outros bancos de dados você precisa usar *providers* de terceiros (no caso do MySQL, da Oracle). A forma mais fácil (e que eu recomendo) de fazer isso é usando o [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/).

Você apenas precisa digitar no *Package Manager Console* o seguinte comando:

> Install-Package MySQL.Data

Se você não souber o que é o NuGet ou não souber usá-lo, podes dar uma olhada no [site](https://www.nuget.org/) e [nesse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudiobr/acelere-seu-desenvolvimento-com-o-nuget) tutorial.

Depois disso, você precisa referenciar o *namespace* **`MySQL.Data.MySqlClient`** sempre que quiser fazer uma conexão.

Aqui vai um pequeno de exemplo, com uma operação de ***insert***

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

static void Main()
{
    //Aqui você substitui pelos seus dados
    var connString = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=usuario;Pwd=senha"; 
    var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABELA1 (CAMPO1) VALUES ('VALOR1')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu! Me ajudou bastante ***=)*** [Pra quem não entender](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/35349137/history)