# É possível fazer uma conexão à um banco de dados MySql sem o MySql.Data.dll?

Tags: c#, mysql

Sempre que vou usar um banco de dados MySql em uma aplicação de console ou windows forms, é preciso ter o dll `MySql.Data.dll` dentro da pasta da aplicação.

Com isso, gostaria de saber, se tem alguma maneira de utilizar o MySql sem um dll. Pensei em tentar utilizar o `System.Data.SqlClient`, mas não sei se é possível.

Comment: Sempre tem, não sei dizer o tamanho do malabarismo para conseguir.

Comment: @bigown Sabe pelo menos por onde devo começar?

Comment: O problema é justamente esse, tem muitas formas espalhadas.

Answer (score 1):

O `System.Data.SqlClient`([referencia aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx)) é exclusividade do SQL Server([como nessa resposta do LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88655/acessar-mysql-com-c)). Sem uma DLL de terceiros é quase impossivél conectar.

De acordo com as minhas pesquisas existe outros modos de conectar o MYSQL ao c# e não é exclusividade do `MySql.Data.dll`. [Nesse site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) encontrei algumas opções de conectores para .NET:

- [MySQLDriverCS](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysqldrivercs/info-and-download/)
- [SevenObjects MySqlClient](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysqldrivercs/info-and-download/)
- [dotConnect for MySQL (former MyDirect.NET and Core Labs MySQLDirect.NET)](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dotconnect-for-mysql/info-and-download/)
- [eInfoDesigns.dbProvider](https://www.connectionstrings.com/einfodesigns-dbprovider/info-and-download/)

Acredito que a `MySQLDriverCS` é a mais utilizada, o resto já não deve ser utilizada no mercado(difícil até de achar referencias). Segue exemplo utilizando o `MySQLDriverCS` encontrado [nesse link](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2006/12/03/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-with-c-asp-net/).

```
    using MySQLDriverCS;
    using System.Data;
    MySQLConnection myConn;
    MySQLDataReader MyReader = null;
    try
    {
      myConn = new MySQLConnection(new MySQLConnectionString("123.456.789.100",
                                                    "mydatabase",
                                                    "user",
                                                    "pass").AsString);
      myConn.Open();
      string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
      MySQLCommand cmd = new MySQLCommand(sql, myConn);  
      MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReaderEx();
      while (MyReader.Read())
      {
        Console.WriteLine( MyReader["Product_Name"].ToString() );
      }
      MyReader.Close();       
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
      Console.WriteLine( ee.ToString() );
    }
    finally
    {
       if (MyReader != null && !MyReader.IsClosed)
       {
          MyReader.Close();
       }
       if (myConn != null && myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
       {
          myConn.Close();
       }
    }
```

Pelo que eu percebi é **MUITO** parecido com o `MySql.Data.dll`.

Comment: Pelo que eu vi todos necessitam de alguma dll ou instalação, nenhum deixa o source code ou algo do tipo.

Comment: @Francisco kkk é que antes de você editar, você disse "com **ESTE** dll"

Comment: @Francisco sem a DLL não é possível.