# Erro de conexão na string connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, conexão

Olá, tentando conectar meu VS ao MySQL pela `string` `connection` recebo toda vez erro que o servidor não foi encontrado, como devo prosseguir?

```
private void btnCadastrarConfirmed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection obj = new SqlConnection("server = localhost; userid = root; database = myshop; persistsecurityinfo = True") ;

    obj.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("GRAZADEUS!!!"); 
}
```

Comment: Poste o código por favor.

Comment: `SqlConnection` não funciona pra MySQL

Comment: O que eu poderia usar então?

Comment: Veja essa resposta [Acessar MySQL com C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88696/60376)

Comment: Valeu galera deu certo :)